# How can I make an image 100 percent the width of its container in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have users uploading images from their mobile device and these images can be either are portrait or landscape. I have these images tiled similar to Instagram posts. The biggest problem I'm having is that portrait images are not rendering at 100 percent of the container width. It's really bizarre.

Here is an example of a "portrait" photo taken by me and visualized using the following code:

```
VStack{
    AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: self.mediaLink))
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
}
.padding(.horizontal, 20)
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
```

Even though I am specifying the width, it still renders incorrectly. It should be `UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40`, which is the same width as its parent `VStack`

[image]

When using `GeometryReader`, my code looks like this:

```
GeometryReader{geo in
    VStack{
        AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: self.mediaLink))
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width)
    }
}
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```

Which is worse!

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Using `.fill` for the aspect ratio makes the images too large and they block everything in the card. The below code does not use `GeometryReader`

```
VStack{
    AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: self.mediaLink))
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
}
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
```

[image]

Comment: Tested your code with just `Image("some_image")` and it works, so the issue is either in `AnimatedImage` or in some other code.

Comment: If you check the preview of the complete view in your canvas, do you see the width of the VStack being the same as the image for the first example you wrote? It might be something related to the height, as experiment have you tried fixing the height to something close to the image expected height?

Comment: @Asperi is correct. The problem is with AnimatedImage. I'm using this dependency for my project. https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI. All I had to do was change `AnimatedImage` to `WebImage`. If you post, I'll mark as answered. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested your code with just Image("some_image") as below and it works (Xcode 12 / iOS 14), so the issue is either in `AnimatedImage` or in some other code.

```
VStack{
    Image("some_image")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
}
.padding(.horizontal, 20)
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `scaledToFill` and `clipped` modifiers

```swift
    VStack{
        AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: self.mediaLink))
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
            .clipped()
    }
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this change will help you:

```
VStack {
    AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: self.mediaLink))
       .resizable()
       .scaledToFit()
}
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
```